# Finding whether a number is a multiple of another

Tags: prolog, failure-slice, successor-arithmetics

Looking at the code below:

```
multiple(X,0).
multiple(X,Y) :- lt(0,X), lt(0,Y), diff(Y,X,D), multiple(X,D).
```

There happens to be something wrong. For your reference:
 lt/2 is whether the first argument is less than the second.
diff/3 is whether the third argument is equal to the first argument minus the second.
lt/2 and diff/3 are defined correctly.

Is there a logical mistake in the definition? Is assuming that 0 is the multiple of every number problematic or is the logical mistake somewhere else? I get correct answers but the query goes to infinite loop I think.

EDIT:
here are the other definitions.

```
natNum(0).
natNum(s(X)) :- natNum(X).

lt(0,s(X)) :- natNum(X).
lt(s(X),s(Y)) :- lt(X,Y).

sum(0,X,X).
sum(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- sum(X,Y,Z).

diff(X,Y,Z) :- sum(Z,Y,X).

?- multiple(X, s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))).
```

where `s(0)` is 1, `s(s(0))` is 2 etc. It gives all the desired answers for X but after the last answer, it gets stuck. I assume in an infinite recursive loop?

Comment: What is not working? What query is failing? Did you `trace.`?

Comment: `?- multiple(X, s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))).` where s(0) is 1, s(s(0)) is 2 etc. It gives all the desired answers for X but after the last answer, it gets stuck. I assume in an infinite recursive loop? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please add the definition of `lt/2` and `diff/3`. How can we tell, if we do not see them!

Comment: edited. :) @false

Comment: Write `X = s(_)` in place of `lt(0,X)` (twice)

Comment: @false same for `Y = s(_)` instead of `lt(0,Y)` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening in your program? Does it loop forever, or does it only take some time since you haven't updated your hardware in recent decades? We cannot tell. (Actually, we could tell by looking at your program, but that is much too complex for the moment).

What we can do with ease is narrow down the source of this costly effort. And this, without a deep understanding of your program.  Let's start with the query:

```
?- multiple(X, s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))).
   X = s(0)
;  X = s(s(0))
;  X = s(s(s(0)))
;  X = s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))
;  loops. % or takes too long
```

Isn't there an easier way to do this? All this semicolon typing. Instead, simply add **`false`** to your query. In this manner the solutions found are no longer shown and we can concentrate on this annoying looping. And, if we're at it, you can also add **`false`** goals into your program! By such goals the number of inferences might be reduced (or stays the same). And if the resulting fragment (called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)) is looping, then this is **a reason** why your original program loops:

```
multiple(_X,0) :- false.
multiple(X,Y) :- lt(0,X), false, lt(0,Y), diff(Y,X,D), multiple(X,D).

natNum(0) :- false.
natNum(s(X)) :- natNum(X), false.

lt(0,s(X)) :- natNum(X), false.
lt(s(X),s(Y)) :- false, lt(X,Y).

?- multiple(X, s(s(s(s(s(s(0))))))), false.
   loops.
```

Do your recognize your program? Only those parts remained that are needed for a loop. And, actually in this case, we have an infinite loop.

To fix this, we need to modify something in the remaining, visible part. I'd go for `lt/2` whose first clause can be generalized to `lt(0, s(_))`.

But wait! Why is it OK to generalize away the requirement that  we have a natural number? Look at the fact `multiple(X,0).` which you have written. You have not demanded that `X` is a natural number either.  This kind of **over-generalizations** often appears in Prolog programs. They improve termination properties at a relatively low price: Sometimes they are too general but all terms that additionally fit into the generalization are not natural numbers. They are terms like `any` or `[a,b,c]`, so if they appear somewhere you know that they do not belong to the solutions.

---

So the idea was to put **`false`** goals into your program such that the resulting program (failure-slice) still loops. In the worst case you put **`false`** at a wrong place and the program terminates.  By trial-and-error you get a minimal failure-slice.  All those things that are now <s>stroked through</s> are **irrelevant**! In particular `diff/3`. So no need to understand it (for the moment). It suffices to look at the remaining program.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, but I could not understand. What does the scribbled part of the code mean? Why did we add `false` to our definitions? Wouldn't that just ignore all these definitions? I am puzzled.

Comment: Read **And if the resulting fragment  ...** That's the point: The remaining program has a lot to do with your original program as it is the reason for its non-termination.

Comment: Anything further you want to be explained?

Comment: **Wouldn't that just ignore all these definitions?** Yes, the failure-slice does not contain `diff/3` because the problem arises already independently of it.